# How to avoid json response recursiveness in parent-child jpa relationship?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa, jackson-databind

I have this issue that I haven't reached to before so I am asking for some help.
I have this entity class

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
class Person {

       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
       @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
       @Type(type = "uuid-char")
       private UUID id;

       @Column
       private String name;

       @Column
       private int age;

       @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
       @ToString.Exclude
       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinTable(name = "person_contact", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
       private Set<Person> contacts;
}
```

The main issue that I have is that when I map this entity to a certain DTO which has the same properties shown above, when I am retrieving it from the controller side as a response, I get recursiveness because something is not right with the 'contacts' relationship. How can I get rid of this issue? I would only want to retrieve the id, age and name from the set not the set itself again and again. How can I ignore that?

Comment: `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 ways of "fixing" this issue:

1. Just remove the `Set<Person>` property from the DTO.
2. In case you use this property and only want to ignore it in the serialization to JSON, add a `@JsonIgnore` annotation to the field, and it wont get serialized in the response.

--EDIT
According to the comment, you want to add this field, and have it show the data for the collection of `Person` but those should not have their "contacts" shown.
You can create a second DTO class that has only the first 3 fields, and instead of adding a `Set<Person>` to the main DTO, add a `Set<PersonContactDto>` or similar.

Comment: but I want the contacts to get into my response but without the set of the contact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your DTO:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"contacts"})
private Set<PersonDto> contacts;
```

This will ignore the `contacts` field inside the set.